# Typing on search bar breaks layout

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have a tableView:

```
tableView = UITableView()
view.addSubview(tableView)

tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let constraints = [tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor), tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor), tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor), tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.height * 0.6)]
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

And my searchController looks like:

```
func setupSearchController() {
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for a candy"
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

When it loads for the first time everything is fine. But when I tap on the search bar to type there, my search bar moves to the top, navigation bar becomes smaller and it breaks my layout and white space appears between tableView and searchBar:

[image]

How can I improve my constraints to move up and down my tableView when the navigation bar sizes are changed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your top constraint of the tableview.
Try replacing this 2 constraint

```
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchController.searchBar.bottomAnchor), 
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
```

With this

```
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
```

The automatic content inset adjustment will do the rest.

Note also that in your table view constraints list you doesn't have a leading/horizontal position constraint. I suggest to add also this constraint

```
tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a typo! I forgot to remove the `searchBar` anchor from the question. I've updated my question but the problem is there.
And I HAVE leading and trailing constraints. Please scroll the code to the right

Comment: I'm sorry. It was my fault! Please look at my question again. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry but I cannot reproduce your issue, with your constraints the tableview content moves up when the search bar is tapped. Please post here or on GitHub a verifiable example.